# Looking for an algorithm that Iterate an item with this constraint

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

I have an array of 10 item. And I have a for cycle from 0 to 20.
I take the position of the array at each index, but when I reach the last position of the array, the next iteration should start from the 5° position of it.

So, somethings like:

```
Array[0]
Array[1]
Array[2]
Array[3]
Array[4] 
Array[5]
Array[6]
Array[7]
Array[8]
Array[9]
Array[4]  <== reached max array's lenght. restart iteration at 5° position
Array[5]
Array[6]
Array[7]
Array[8]
Array[9]
Array[4]  <== reached max array's lenght. restart iteration at 5° position
Array[5]
Array[6]
Array[7]
Array[8]
```

At this moment I have:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    value = MyArray[(i % MyArray.length)];
}
```

but I don't know how to put that "restart at 5° position". 
I think somethings like:

```
i % MyArray.length * "number of time 10 is inside 20"
```

but I don't find the right Javascript function.

Comment: why don't you simply use an `if` statement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one two separate variable: one as a counter and another as a iterator:

```
var j = 0, i = 0;
while(i++ < 20) {
    if (j === MyArray.length) {
        j = 4;
    }
    console.log(MyArray[j]);
    j++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a function instead of a loop :

```
var len = MyArray.length;
(function doLoopandRestartat5(val){

    console.log(MyArray[val]);

    if(val<len) { doLoopandRestartat5(++val) }
    else { doLoopandRestartat5(4); }

})(0);
```

*Or something like that .. typing quickly here ..*